# why we use the Impression Tracking?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a question . why we use the Impression Tracking ? I have read the salesforce   marketing docs. but i am not able to understand what is the practical use of it.
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Hi Adarsh. Please remember to [mark my answer as accepted](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if it has been helpful. This will allow other users of SFSE to easily identify questions with valuable answers.

Answer (score 2):

One should use Impression Regions for keeping track on dynamic content in highly data driven emails. When either using dynamic content block or coding your own sophisticated logic directly in Ampscript, it is very essential to know what content was actually included in the email. This is what Impression Region is for.

A use case could be an area in your email, which was shown conditionally based on the age and loyalty tier of your recipient, potentially resulting in 20+ possible combination. Especially is multiple dynamic content blocks or ampscript logic is used in a single email, it can be difficult to predict who is receiving what content. Imagine you see low click numbers for a specific CTA in your email. However this is only included in certain conditions, and hence not to all recipients. To find out how many, and which recipients, received an email with that CTA, you must use Impression Regions to keep track on that.

When using the standard dynamic content block, the tags for impression region tracking are set automatically, but you need to set them yourself if working with Ampscript:

```ampscript
%%[ IF (@ageTier == "20-29" and @loyaltyLevel = "Gold" THEN ]%%
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("Something_specific_for_you")=%%
Here is some content only some of the recipients are getting to see.
%%=EndImpressionRegion(0)=%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

In the above example, if you don't math the criteria in IF statement, you will not get to see the content, and the impression region will not be triggered. If you match the criteria, your recipient will be included in the tracking extract with impression regions, in the context of this particular sendout, having "Something_specific_for_you" registered there.

Please be aware, that `BeginImpressionRegion()` function only supports static values for the region name. However you can use the workaround below, if your name needs to be set dynamically:

```ampscript
%%=TreatAsContent(concat("%","%=BeginImpressionRegion('",@blockName,"')=%","%"))=%%
```

There is no report on Impression Regions, but you can export the data in [Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&language=en_US&type=5) in Automation Studio:

[image]

I have collected this and other insights in this article [going more in depth on impression region tracking](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/reporting/impression-tracking-in-marketing-cloud/).